# How can I get all the software link?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have this code:

```
import urllib
import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.downloadcrew.com/?act=search&cat=51"
pageHtml = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageHtml)

for a in soup.select("div.productListingTitle a[href]"):
    try:
        print (a["href"]).encode("utf-8","replace")
    except:
        print "no link"

        pass
```

But when I run it, I only get 20 links only. The output should be more than 20 links.

Comment: Why would it be more than 20 links? There are only 20 links per page.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Because at the bottom still got a lot pages.

Comment: You only downloaded the first page. You have to loop through all of them.

Comment: @Blorgbeard How can I do that?

Comment: Click on a page link and look at the address. Probably something like `&page=123` in there. So loop from 1 to the number of pages, and generate all the page URLs, downloading each one.

Comment: @Blorgbeard How I can make loop if the link start with &page=0 and do not know the end page?

Comment: Try a `while` loop and just stop when you get a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you only download the first page of content.

Just use a loop to donwload all pages:

```
import urllib
import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for i in xrange(3):
    url = "http://www.downloadcrew.com/?act=search&page=%d&cat=51" % i
    pageHtml = urllib.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pageHtml)

    for a in soup.select("div.productListingTitle a[href]"):
        try:
            print (a["href"]).encode("utf-8","replace")
        except:
            print "no link"
```

if you do'nt know the count of pages, you can

```
import urllib
import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

i = 0
while 1:
    url = "http://www.downloadcrew.com/?act=search&page=%d&cat=51" % i
    pageHtml = urllib.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pageHtml)

    has_more = 0
    for a in soup.select("div.productListingTitle a[href]"):
        has_more = 1
        try:
            print (a["href"]).encode("utf-8","replace")
        except:
            print "no link"
    if has_more:
        i += 1
    else:
        break
```

I run it on my computer and it get 60 link of three pages.

Good luck~

Comment: that if 3 pages..what about if dont know the total page?

Comment: you can write a while loop and break util that no result can   get . For instance: in my answer.

Comment: Thank you man. It works!. I forgot no write d inside %d and that is why while loop is not working.